Can the combination of pure load and a store model the RMW operation?
In a program, if all operations to an atomic object are RMW operations, due to rule [atomic.order] p10, we get a guarantee that a modification in the modification order of that atomic object can only be read by one RMW operation. We can build up critical sections based on that guarantee.
For example:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
int main(){
  std::atomic<int> state = {0};
  int protect_v = 0;
  std::thread t1([&](){
     int expected = 0;
     if(state.compare_exchange_strong(expected,1,std::memory_order::release,std::memory_order::acquire)){
          protect_v  = 2;
       }else{
          std::cout<< "t1 read: "<<protect_v  <<"\n";
       }
  });
  std::thread t2([&](){
     int expected = 0;
     if(state.compare_exchange_strong(expected,1,std::memory_order::release,std::memory_order::acquire)){
          protect_v  = 3;
       }else{
         std::cout<< "t2 read: "<<protect_v  <<"\n";
       }
  });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}

However, if any RMW operation in the above program is changed to a load operation followed by a store operation, Is that guarantee still held? It appears to me that, in this case, if that load reads 0 and that store operation stores 1, and even though there is no interference between such two operations, another RMW operation can still read 0, and vice versa. So, the guarantee is broken by this change, right?
Q1:
If we want a modification in the modification order of a single atomic object only to be read by one operation, all operations to that object must be RMW operations, such that they contend to read that value.
Q2:
std::atomic<bool> flag = false;
std::atomic<int> state = 0;
// thread 1:
if(state.load(std::memory_order::seq_cst)==0){
   state.store(1,std::memory_order::seq_cst);
   flag.store(true,std::memory_order::seq_cst);
}
// thread 2:
while(!flag.load(std::memory_order::relaxed)){}
state.exchange(1,std::memory_order::seq_cst);

The RMW operation exchange can still read the value 0, right?
Q3:
How are the load and exchange ordered in the single total order? [atomics.order] p3 says:

An atomic operation A on some atomic object M is coherence-ordered before another atomic operation B on M if


[...]
A and B are not the same atomic read-modify-write operation, and there exists an atomic modification X of M such that A reads the value stored by X and X precedes B in the modification order of M, or



However, the initialization to state is not an atomic modification as per [atomics.types.operations] p3

Effects: Initializes the object with the value desired.
Initialization is not an atomic operation ([intro.multithread]).


To get mutual exclusion without atomic RMWs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm and related (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm).  Q1: You're right that you must not have any pure loads.  If it's ok for some modifications not to be read at all, some operations can be pure stores.  If every modification must be read by exactly one reader, then yes they all need to be RMWs.

Q3: it's a longstanding defect(?) that the initializer isn't a modification at all, but its value still needs to be considered the first entry in the modification order for other stuff to make sense.

@PeterCordes Why isn't the initialization a modification? I think it's a modification but not atomic.

For an atomic<> in static storage with a compile-time-constant initializer, there's no modification at run-time (other than when the program is loaded/mapped into memory).  For non-static object, I don't know if standard says anything specific that would answer the question of whether a std::atomic object (and its modification order) exists at all before initialization is complete.

@PeterCordes BTW, after roughly looking at the algorithm you linked in the above comment, is seq_cst the key way(i.e. form the single total order) to prevent both flag in the loop from reading false to simultaneously enter the critical sections?

@PeterCordes static initialization is also a initialization. Initialization starts the lifetime of the object(basic.life#1), and initialization should be considered as a modification from the English phrase, although not formal definition.

Yes, mutual exclusion without atomic RMW relies on seq_cst.  In terms of real hardware, the key thing is flushing to store buffer so you can read what other threads see when you reload a variable you just stored.

Variables with static storage duration are initialized as a consequence of program initiation. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#1 .  I'm fine with considering initialization a modification in terms of standardese, but the plain English phrase does not imply that.  With constant-initialized static storage in real implementations, the memory location has its initial value from the moment it exists at all.  The initialization was done by the compiler filling in values in the .data section (or .rodata for const) which is loaded or memory-mapped, or .rodata could even be in ROM.

Anyway, regardless, the initial value can be read by any atomic operation, and counts as an entry in the mod order even for cases where the standard says things like "there exists an atomic modification X".  At least I think it's meaningful to say that the initializer is coherence-ordered-before any operation that variable.  (It needs to happen-before any other operation or else the behaviour is undefined, so it's maybe not interesting to talk about its coherence-order.)

@PeterCordes As the quote I cited above, there is rule that: All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization. This implies the standard does not intend to distinguish whether the initialization occurs at compile-time or run-time. In other words, do we consider "happens before" as a property of runtime or compile-time?

@PeterCordes Whether the modification of the initialization can be that X is important when there are two operations A and B, A is load and B is a store, A reads the value of the initialization, and we want to figure out the order of A and B in the single total order S. For example, Peterson's algorithm is that case.

Yes, static initialization happens-before any run-time stuff.  The question is whether it's a "modification" of anything.  Maybe the authors of the standard assume it is, even for a static const atomic<int> burned into ROM or memory-mapped from a read-only page; the physical storage had to get written with that value at some point, and that counts as a modification. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.2 says the lifetime of a variable starts "its initialization (if any) is complete", so variable lifetime can start before the program runs, apparently.  So no obstacle there.

Anyway, regardless of whether initialization is a modification, you're right it's not an atomic modification, and there is a known problem with the standard for initial values of atomic objects.

@PeterCordes After looking at Peterson's algorithm, IIUC, both processes can enter the busy wait, isn't it? Just as the execution order that: flag_0 = true, turn  = 1, flag_1 = true, (flag_1 && turn == 1) == true, turn = 0, then (flag_0 && turn ==0) ==true, and this execution order can form a valid single total order S, which likes a deadlock?

It's also possible to do both atomic and non-atomic modifications to the same object via atomic_ref.  I wonder if the same defect applies here.  Suppose we have int x; atomic_ref<int> a(x); and we do x = 1;.  Later, after appropriate synchronization (so no data race), thread 1 does a.load() and gets 1, and thread 2 does a.store(2).  It seems to me that by a strict reading, neither of these latter two operations is coherence-ordered before the other, and so it is possible that the store precedes the load in the seq_cst total order.  Which can't possibly be intended.

@NateEldredge It would be great to detail this in https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/641 to make the issue be recognized.

@NateEldredge According to the conclusion in the note atomics.order p5, if the store modification is the last one that precedes the load in S, the load must read that value. However, this conclusion is derived from [atomics.order] p3.3, which also does not work for your case and sounds like another counter-example for that wording.
